# Proof that a linear code is self-orthogonal iff it is classically self-orthogonal

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields, orthogonality, coding-theory, field-trace

Below is a theorem and proof as appears in https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9608006.pdf

**Notation:**

We are working over $GF(4)$

Trace inner product: $u*v=Tr(u.\bar{v})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Tr(u_{i}\bar{v_{i}})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_{i}v_{i}^{2} + u_{i}^{2}v_{i}) (mod2)$

The conjugate over GF(4): $\bar{x}=x^{2}$

The dual code wrt the Hermitian trace inner product is $C^{\perp}=$ {$u \in GF(4)^{n} | u*c=0 \forall c \in C$}

$C$ is self-orthogonal if $C \subseteq C^{\perp}$

**Theorem:**

A linear code $C$ is self-orthogonal (with respect to the trace inner product) if and only if it is classically self-orthogonal with respect to the Hermitian inner product.

**Proof:**

The condition is clearly sufficient. Suppose $C$ is self-orthogonal. For $u,v \in C$ let $u.\bar{v}= \alpha + \beta w$ $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

Then:

$Tr(u.\bar{v})=0$ implies $\beta = 0$

$Tr(u.\bar{w}\bar{v})=0$ implies $\alpha = 0$

So $u.\bar{v}=0$

**Question:**

I want to check that my reasoning is correct:

$Tr(u.\bar{v})=0$  implies that $\beta=0$.

$Tr(u.\bar{v})=Tr(\alpha + w \beta)=Tr(\alpha) + Tr(\beta w)$. This is a linear code, we can distribute additively over the trace: $Tr(\alpha)=0$ because $\alpha$ is $0$ or $1$ and $Tr(0)=Tr(1)=0$

then $Tr(\beta w)$ has to be $0$ as well, meaning $\beta w$ must be $1$ or $0$, but $\beta w \neq 1$, so $\beta w =0$, meaning $\beta=0$.

Then $Tr(u.\bar{w}\bar{v})=Tr(\bar{w} \alpha + w \beta) = Tr(w^{2}\alpha +w^{3} \beta )=Tr((w+1)\alpha + \beta)=Tr(w\alpha) + Tr(\alpha) + Tr(\beta)=Tr(w \alpha) =0$ so $\alpha=0$

---

A note on inner products:

First note that in $GF(4)$, $\bar{x} = x^{2}$ and $\bar{u}=\bar{u_{1}},\dots,\bar{u_{n}} = u_{1}^{2}, \dots, u_{n}^{2}$

**Hermitian trace inner product** of two vectors in $GF(4)$ of length $n$, $u=u_{1},\dots,u_{n}$, $v=v_{1},\dots,v_{n}$ is defined by:
$$u*v=Tr(u.\bar{v})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Tr(u_{i}\bar{v_{i}})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_{i}v_{i}^{2} + u_{i}^{2}v_{i}) (mod2)$$ This incidentally also gives us the number($mod2$) of positions in which $u$ and $v$ have different non-zero values.
We describe the dual of $C$, $C^{\perp}$ with respect to this Hermitian trace inner product. A code is **self-orthogonal** if $C \subseteq C^{\perp}$ (defined wrt Hermitian trace inner product).

**Hermitian inner product** of two vectors in $GF(4)$ of length $n$ is $$u.\bar{v}$$
A code $C$ is **classically self-orthogonal** if  it is orthogonal wrt the Hermitian inner product.

**Symplectic inner product** of two vectors $(a|b)$, $(a'|b')$ in $GF(2)$ of length $2n$ is defined as:
$$((a|b),(a'|b'))=a.b' + a'.b$$

Comment: You seem to discuss three inner products: *trace inner product*, *Hermitian trace inner product* and *Hermitian inner product*. You also discuss *self-orthogonal* as well as *classically self-orthogonal*. Care to give the precise meanings of all those terms? I may be able to guess a few, but would rather not.

Comment: Of course, sorry I should have been more precise. I added a note at the end of the question explaining some of the inner products as I understand them, hopefully that is sufficient!